# Runtime Calculation Sort-Algortihm

Tags: runtime-analysis, sorting

I'm really struggling with the following exercise and I would really appreciate your help:
I have to calculate the expected runtime of a sort Algorithm with the following variants:

```
Variant   Runtime Behavior
1            n(n-1)
2              n
3            n log(n)
```

Given is, that the runtime for variant 1 is 1000 elements(n) is 20ms.
With the calculation for the other elements from variant 1, I have no problem because it's O(n^2) but I really don't know how to calculate the values for variant 2 & 3.

```
Variant    Length n    expected runtime in ms
   1        500          20ms * 0.5^2 = 5ms
   1        4'000        20ms * 4^2   = 320ms
   2        2'000'000    ?
   3        4'096        ?
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Kind Regards

Comment: You correctly evaluated the times for variant 1 as $20\left(\dfrac n{1000}\right)^2$. So you should be able to tell the time for a single elementary operation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not even mention big-O here because that is for asymptotic behaviour and f(1000) doesn’t give you the slightest clue what f(2000000) would be.

You are given that the runtime is f(n) = c x g(n) for three different functions c. Given the value of c x g(1000) for the first function g, you calculate c. Then you substitute c and n for all the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really tried to understand it but what is then c in this case? I really don't understand the concept.

Comment: You don't know what c is. You might run this code on a 20 year old computer, or a brand new one, and the time is different.

Answer (score 0):

The times are

$$\begin{align}&c\,n(n-1)\\
&c\,n\\
&c\,n\log n\end{align}$$

So as soon as you know $c$, you can compute all cases for any $n$.

> $$c=\frac{20\text{ ms}}{1000\cdot999}.$$